# Invariant dimension property of a ring $R$ which admits a homomorphism to a division ring $D$

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring which admits a homomorphism to a division ring $D$. I know that if the homomorphism is surjective, then the ring has invariant dimension property. But if the homomorphism is not surjective, is it still true that $R^n$ isomorphic to $R^m$ as $R$-modules only when $n=m$? If this is not true, any counterexample? 
(The ring $R$ has identity.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, much more is true:

> If $f:R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism, and $S$ has IBN property, then $R$ also has the IBN property.

This follows immediately form the following characterization of IBN rings: a ring $R$ has the IBN property iff for $A\in M_{m\times n}(R)$ and $B\in M_{n\times m}(R)$ with the property $AB=I_m$ and $BA=I_n$ it follows $m=n$. (See also Lam, *Lectures on Modules and Rings*, Remark 1.5.)

Answer (score 1):

It is true if the homomorphism is injective, because:

- Stably finite rings (i.e. rings for which, for any square matrices $A$ and $B$, $AB=I\implies BA=I$) have the *invariant basis number* property,
- Division rings are stably finite,
- A subring of a stably finite ring is stably finite.

Comment: How to show that a division ring is stably finite? It seems that stably finiteness is stronger than IBN.

Comment: Noetherian and artinian rings are stably finite. Don't ask me how to prove the latter. And, yes, stably finiteness is stronger than the I.B.N. property.