# Prove that if a ring R has IBN, then so does R/ I for every proper two-sided ideal I.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules

> Prove that if a ring $R$ has IBN (invariant basis number), then so does $R/I$ for every proper two-sided
>   ideal I.

My attempt: $R$ has IBN, then $R^m\cong R^n$ implies $m=n$. I wish to show that $(R/I)^m\cong (R/I)^n$ implies $m=n$. Should there is a map $R/I\rightarrow R$? then the basis of $(R/I)^m$ gives a basis of $R^m$.

Comment: There is always a canonical map $R\to R/I$, but the other way there might not be a map (consider $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\to \Bbb  Z$ which, depending on your definition of ring and homomorphism, has either no maps or just the trivial map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition is incorrect.

Take any ring $R$ with the IBN and any nonzero ring $S$ which does not have the IBN.  Then $R\times S$ has the IBN, but $\frac{R\times S}{R\times \{0\}}\cong S$ does not.

The correct version of the proposition is that if $R/I$ is a nonzero quotient with the IBN, then $R$ also has the IBN. That is [asked and answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3424923/29335) elsewhere on ths site.

OR you could also say "if $R$ does *not* have the IBN, then none of its nonzero quotients $R/I$ has IBN either.

Comment: Surprised it was a wrong exercise. this exercise come from the Advanced modern algebra by Rotman.

Comment: @Yunhao Edition? Problem number? Page?

Comment: Based on what I can see online, it seems to be in the 2010 edition, but not in the 2015 or 2017 editions. In the 2017 edition, either the index is wrong or the subject of IBN was removed entirely from the book.  I'm amazed at how much is changing in each version.

Comment: There are *a lot* of errata for this book, in many versions. You'll probably need [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rotman/)

Comment: Third edition presented by AMS. Page 490.